# How to Get Destination Port Along with Target IP using Seeker Tool

Tags: python, json

this code is for seeker tool on Github it gives`your text` the targets public IP address i want to add a function to also get the destination port of the target with the IP address
i want help to adjust the tool code to achieve this goal